# Mathematica 10 cannot solve definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

*Mathematica* 10 fails to solve the following integral, saying that it does not converge.

```
Integrate[HermiteH[5, x] HermiteH[6, x] HermiteH[5,x] Exp[-x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

This is clearly wrong. The same evaluated in *Mathematica* 9 returns

```
36864000 Sqrt[Pi]
```

Is there a solution for this issue, except going back to version 9?

Comment: `int = Integrate[HermiteH[5, x] HermiteH[6, x] HermiteH[5, x] Exp[-x^2], x];
Limit[int, x -> Infinity] - Limit[int, x -> -Infinity]` gives `36864000 Sqrt[Pi]`

Comment: Please report this at support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Has this been fixed in 10.0.1?

Comment: Seems to be OK in 10.0.2.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [(61866)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61866)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can use [`Expectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Expectation.html) on a [`NormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NormalDistribution.html), as I've shown before in [Mathematica complaints that convergent integral diverges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61866/mathematica-complaints-that-convergent-integral-diverges/63139#63139).  (Indeed this question is nearly a duplicate of that one.)  The expectation of polynomials in a normally distributed variable is a special case in `Expectation` and are evaluated very quickly.

The argument is integrated against the pdf:

```
PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2]], x]
(* E^-x^2/Sqrt[π] *)
```

To get the OP's integral we have to multiply by the constant factor `Sqrt[π]`:

```
Sqrt[π] Expectation[HermiteH[5, x] HermiteH[6, x] HermiteH[5, x], 
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2]]]
(* 36864000 Sqrt[π] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Integrate[
 HermiteH[5, x] HermiteH[6, x] HermiteH[5, 
   x] Exp[-x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]

(*36864000 Sqrt[\[Pi]]*)
```

Comment: "[PrincipalValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrincipalValue.html) is an option for Integrate that specifies whether the Cauchy principal value should be found for a *definite* integral." - Does that make sense here?